# ANDROID SQLITE DATABASE insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite

the database class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET = "street";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY = "place";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
private HashMap hp;

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table contacts " +
                    "(id integer primary key, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertContact  (String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("street", street);
    contentValues.put("place", place);
    db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}

public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("street", street);
    contentValues.put("place", place);
    db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

the activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button login;
EditText student_id;
EditText password;
TextView message;
DBHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    student_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.student_id);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    message=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.logResult);
    message.setText("");

    db.insertContact("jon","9595749944","r@hotmail.com","a","usa");

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(student_id.getText().toString());
            int result= db.numberOfRows();
            if (result == 1) {
                message.setText("Invalid User");
            } else {

                message.setText("valid User" );


            }
        }
    });

}
```

But,When the button is pressed the insertion in not occur and app close 
where is the problem?? help?????????????? I want to insert data in database when the app is created how?

Comment: "app close" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: how to trace on actual device? the emulator not work??

Comment: The instructions that I linked to work for both devices and emulators.

Answer (score 0):

your call is outside of the onclick , first try:

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

           db.insertContact("jon","9595749944","r@hotmail.com","a","usa");

    }
});
```